# Why is a megaparsec considered to be a useful distance in astronomy?

Tags: observational-astronomy, distances

Is the megaparsec fundamental or man made? I have read that galaxy clusters are megaparsecs wide for example.

Comment: This question would benefit from some more background - what was the context in which you ask the question.  Was there a use of megaparsecs that seemed not to be useful? Is there another unit that you would consider better - and why? What do you understand the definition of the megaparsec to be?

Answer (score 3):

Every unit is "man-made". Yet within a given system of units you will end up with a set of 'fundamental units' which can be used to express every other property. There are systems which make conversion and calculations easy, others which make it needlessly complicated.

For SI these fundamental units are kilograms, metres, seconds, mol, Kelvin, candela and Amperes. Everything else can be derived. The megaparsec is as fundamental as is the foot or furlong - yet the megaparsec (thus million parsec) is useful to express cosmological distances, while the foot and furlong are not.

Comment: Universal constants can be used as units. And they are not man-made. In relativity, for instance, the speed of light is used as a unit.

Comment: @Dieudonné well, yes. Kinda. The SI base units are actually defined in terms of such kind of constants. One surely could devise a system where you express everything in terms of these.... e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units

Comment: Constants are not interchangeable with units. A constant is a quantity (186,000, or 2, or 7.4) which may or may not have an associated unit. A unit is what we're measuring with the number. The speed-of-light label "c" belongs to the constant 299,792,458 m/s. So, no, _c_ is not a unit, but you can pair it with a coefficient so that _2c_ means "599,584,916 meters traveled in a second", and you may also define other constants in terms of _c_ as long as you express the unit correctly.

Comment: @AriLacenski Yes and no. A constant is not the same as a unit, of course. But you can define a unit $\textrm{c}$ so that the speed of light constant is $c = 1 \textrm{c}$. Then $\textrm{c}$ is a unit, but it is by definition not the same as the constant $c$. Nb. I use an italic $c$ to specify the constant and a non-italic $\textrm{c}$ for the unit, to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 3):

A parsec, and by extension a million parsecs, is essentially a multiple of the astronomical unit, which is related to the distance between the Earth and the Sun.

There is nothing fundamental about it, since the distance between the Earth and the Sun varies with time.